# Estimation of a sum by an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, riemann-sum

In a lecture my professor wrote:

$$\sum_i f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})=\int f(x)dx + o(\delta)
$$

where $\delta$ is the equi-distance $x_i-x_{i-1}$.

I know that this Riemann sum is approximating the integral as the distance goes to zero. I was just wondering why is true that the error is of order $o(\delta)$?

Comment: This could be useful: https://people.math.osu.edu/broaddus.9/116101-F2017/files/ExampleRiemann.pdf

Comment: @Gary Thanks. I try to follow it, but shouldn't it be big-O instead of little-O then?

Comment: Indeed, it should be a big-$\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @Gary thank you .